# Error: Header name must be a valid RFC 7230 (section 3.2) field-name in Magento2 custom payment module

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

```
$header_array = array('Accept: application/json',
                              "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
                              'Accept-Charset: utf-8',
                              'Fecha: '.$fecha,
                              'Autorizacion: '.$firma);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

```
$this->_response->setHttpResponseCode(200)
    ->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true)
    ->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true)
    ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8;', true)
    ->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content), true)
    ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . yourfilename . '"', true)
    ->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'), true)
    ->setBody('yourdata')
    ->sendResponse();
```